# Glassfish v3 - how to disable stack trace on server side log

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, webserver, java-server, server-administration

I want to disable the stack trace on server side log in Glassfish v3? Is there any option to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use `Log Rotate Manager`, it will help you to manage the logs. Take a look here: https://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/managing_rotated_log_files.

If you still want to disable them then you need to play around with log levels, take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#gklml